# How do we know that our bodies contain stardust?

Tags: biology

How do we know we are made of stardust? As our cells divide, are our atoms repurposed from existing materials or spontaneously generated?  Do we consume materials after we are born that contain elements that were in stars? This I would understand.  Or, as our cells are initially dividing after conception, but before birth, are we already repurposing existing materials to grow?

Comment: This is really a question to ask on [Biology.SE].  Or maybe [Physics.SE]

Comment: Probably physics.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! In order to get a better reception for this post, you want to include why it has to do with world building. As it stands now, it is better suited for other sites. This question is also somewhat confusing, you might want to clarify what star dust is.

Comment: Just at a guess, I suspect that the world you're designing is such that "stardust" means something more than a purely modern-mechanistic analysis -- atoms don't appear from nowhere, so we're made of the same atoms as were once stars -- might suggest. For example, "some special people are made of a remarkably large percentage of the same type of stars, star-events, etc., and this has specific implications for their superpowers." If you can explain a bit of what you're getting at, people here might be able to help you with your project.

Comment: I'll recommend [Astronomy](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), too. We have a few related questions over there; I'll see if I can dig them up.

Comment: You can't deduce the source of an atom simply by looking at it. You have to agree with the (very reasonable) theory that light elements were created at the original singularity, and heavier elements created later in gravity bound fusion reactors (i.e. stars)

Answer (score 2):

All atoms were at some point in a star somewhere. Atoms do not spontaneously generate(Outside of very specific conditions, such as those in supercolliders). As we grow we consume materials whose atoms originated in stars and then re-purpose those existing materials to grow.

Comment: Not all atoms were in a star; gas and dust clouds make up a substantial portion of the mass of the galaxy. But the heavier elements *did* have to made in stars - in supernovae, too!